# How to get a row in SQLite by index (not by id)

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

Is there a way to get a row by its index/position in table, rather than by its id?

For example I have 3 rows with IDs:

```
Record1
Record2
Record3
```

Now if I delete the second row using its id, the remaining rows will be like this:

```
Record1
Record3
```

Because I'm using `ListView` position to determine which row in the database to delete, the next time I try to delete second row, I will get exception because row with id 2 doesn't exist.

So is there a method that can retrieve row by its index in table?

Comment: As fas as I know, no. By the way, what exactly is the "index"? How should the database knwo in what order you display the data in your list?

Comment: what is the alternative then?

Comment: But how? what other than position in list to use to determin which row to delete?

Comment: You should use a `CursorAdapter` with your `ListView`.

Comment: "Because I'm using ListView position to determine which row in the database to delete, the next time I try to delete second row, I will get exception because row with id 2 doesn't exist." Simply delete the appropriate row using the database's primary key, not position.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The better route to go will be to fetch the id of the record from the object represented by `ListView` item and then use that to get the correct record in the database. In your `ListView`'s `OnItemClickListener`, the `onItemClick` event takes the `AdapterView` as the first argument and the index of the selected item as the second. Get that item from the adapter and cast it to the type it represents.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    YourClass c = (YourClass)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
    //index of the record to delete can now be accessed at c.id
}
```

However, if you really want to get the *nth* record, I believe you can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName LIMIT 1 OFFSET n;
```

Where n is the index you're after. This also assumes that your results are ordered in the same fashion as they are in your `ListView`.

Comment: It worked, second one, with LIMIT and OFFSET. Thanks. Didn't try other one.

Comment: Glad it helped, but I'd *strongly* encourage you to go back and work it the other way.

Answer (score 2):

*SQLite3* has been greatly improved since the introduction of Android OS. From the [official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) (and in my own words):

> All rows within SQLite tables have a 64-bit signed integer key that uniquely identifies the row within its table. This integer is usually called the **"rowid"**. The rowid value can be accessed using one of the special case-independent names: `rowid`, `oid`, or `_rowid_`, in place of a column name. (In the early Android SQLite implementations you had to use `_id` to access the index.)

So today you can do:

```sql
    SELECT rowid,* FROM tt LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2;
    SELECT rowid,* FROM tt WHERE rowid=2;
    SELECT rowid,* FROM tt WHERE rowid=(SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM tt); -- to get last row index
```